# Error while saving user with other details in model in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to take title, thumbnail, description from user and when user upload it my model get user and save it but i am getting this error on every page of my website

> OperationalError at / no such column: shop_upload_detail.user_id
>
> Request Method:   GET Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/ Django
> Version:  3.2 Exception Type: OperationalError Exception Value:    no
> such column: shop_podcast_detail.user_id Exception
> Location: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py,
> line 423, in execute Python
> Executable:   C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
> Python Version:   3.9.4 Python Path:
> ['C:\Users\admin\Documents\Django e commerce\ecommerce',
> 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python39.zip',
> 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\DLLs',
> 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib',
> 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39',
> 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages',
> 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32',
> 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32\lib',
> 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin']
> Server time:  Thu, 06 May 2021 05:39:44 +0000

my models.py file

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# Create your models here.
class Upload_detail(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="", null=False, blank=False)

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
    tubnail = models.ImageField(upload_to="podcast_images", default="", max_length=5000)

    description = models.TextField(max_length=300, default="")

    date_published = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)




class Poster(models.Model):
    poster_images = models.ImageField(upload_to="poster_images", max_length=5000)
```

views.py

```
def register(response):
    if response.method == "POST":
        form = RegisterForm(response.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            new_user = authenticate(username=form.cleaned_data['username'], password=form.cleaned_data['password1'],)

            login(response, new_user)

        return redirect("/")
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()

    return render(response, "register.html", {"form":form})

def new(request):
    form = new_Upload(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

        return redirect('/')

    else:
        form = new_Upload()

    return render(request, 'upload.html', {"form":form})
```

upload.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Upload_detail

class Podcast_Upload(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Upload_detail
        fields = ['title', 'tubnail', 'description']
```

**but then i notice if i write anything except user in models.py then it is working but in my database in upload details user name is comming like "---------" like this**

```
user_name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="", null=False, blank=False)
```

why if i am using user_name in place of user i am getting no error but i am also not getting username what should i do.

Comment: Did you run `manage.py makemigrations` and `manage.py migrate` first?

Comment: @Selcuk Yes even i delete migration files many times then rerun `manage.py makemigrations` and `manage.py migrate` but still it is not working

Comment: @Selcuk Yes even i delete migration files many times then rerun manage.py makemigrations and manage.py migrate but still it is not working